# How to sort URLs based on path/levels?

Tags: sorting, url

I want to sort URLs based on path/levels. How can I do it ? (It can be a online tool/PHP/bash/linux script), Anything is okay.

```
example.com/a
example.com/b
example.com/c
example.com/aaa/1
example.com/aaa/2
example.com/aaa/3
example.com/aaa/bbb/apath
example.com/aaa/bbb/bpath
example.com/aaa/bbb/cpath
example.com/aaa/bbb/path/1
example.com/aaa/bbb/path/2
```

Answer (score 1):

I `echo`'d your inputs, reordered, into a loop.
I assigned the input line to a second key, striped the non-delimiters, and prepended the key, then printed the new line.

I piped the loop to a `sort`, and piped the sorted output to a `sed` to strip off the prepended key.

I haven't used the ${x///} construct much, so there's probably a cleaner way to do it than this conversion to underscores, and I'm looking forward to seeing it, lol

```
$: echo "example.com/a
example.com/c
example.com/aaa/bbb/path/1
example.com/aaa/3
example.com/aaa/bbb/apath
example.com/aaa/2
example.com/aaa/bbb/bpath
example.com/aaa/1
example.com/aaa/bbb/cpath
example.com/b
example.com/aaa/bbb/path/2" | 
  while read line
  do key=${line//\//_}
     key=${key//[^_]/}
     printf "$key\t$line\n"
 done | sort |sed 's/^_*          //'
example.com/a
example.com/b
example.com/c
example.com/aaa/1
example.com/aaa/2
example.com/aaa/3
example.com/aaa/bbb/apath
example.com/aaa/bbb/bpath
example.com/aaa/bbb/cpath
example.com/aaa/bbb/path/1
example.com/aaa/bbb/path/2
```

Comment: Same logic with `awk` would be quicker.

Comment: Thanks, let me check

Comment: Hi, I used this code. It does sorting based on path in a alphabetical order. I want to sort based on levels. I mean, the level one to be sorted first, and then level 2 and 3.

Comment: Let's clarify - it sorts based on how many subdirectories there are first, *then* alphabetically. If that's not what you wanted, please clarify.